# queryDSL subquery leading to UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: jpql, querydsl

In a QueryDSL `JPQLQuery` containing a `Predicate` like

```
private static Predicate getPredicate(String filter) {
        QFooEntity foo = new QFooEntity("foo");
        QBarEntity bar = new QBarEntity("bar");
        return JPAExpressions.select().from(foo, bar)
        .where(...).matches(...).exists();
}
```

an `UnsupportedOperationException` is thrown in `JPASubQuery.iterate()` when I try to `fetch()` the query results.

Debugging the code clearly shows that's the subquery predicate causing the exception.

Any idea on how to solve this, i.e. transform this predicate to a subquery accepted by queryDSL?